# What to use instead of getaddrinfo() and freeaddrinfo() targetting legacy Windows?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock2

By requirement, I'm targeting old legacy Windows systems (9x branch) where `getaddrinfo()` and `freeaddrinfo()` are not available.

What can I use instead of that? The code I'm using right now is extracted from the MSDN site (I'm testing it in a Vista computer):

```
...
/* WinSock data: */
WSADATA wsaData;
/* Initialize the WinSock data: */
short int iResult = 0;
if (iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData)) {
    printf("Failed to init Winsock library: %d.\n", iResult);
    return -1;
}

printf("\n  Opening connection to server.");
/* Variables for a connection: */
struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;
/* Initialize the connection: */
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
/* Resolve the server address and port: */
if (iResult = getaddrinfo("x", "80", &hints, &result)) {
    printf("Server resolution failed: %d.\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return -2;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way was `gethostbyname` and `getnameinfo`. Usage is explained well here:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostbynameman.html